# Overlapping Models in Myrrix

Tags: mahout, myrrix, mahout-recommender

I'm currently using Myrrix to get recommendations as follows:

```
User,Item,Score
```

But I'd like to add the ability to recommend as follows:

```
Collection,Item,1
```

(where `Collection` is a group of `Item`s - I could have called this Album and Song, but yes, the actual use case does make sense...)

Now, the answer at [Multiple models in Myrrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16721216/954442) suggests I should split across multiple Myrrix instances, which I'd rather not do if possible (memory overhead is a slight concern).

It just so happens that `Collection` Ids are guaranteed to be in the top half of the long range, and `User` Ids in the bottom half, i.e. they cannot overlap. Does that mean that as long as I use the rescorer to keep the two types apart, I can keep everything together without the two sets of recommendations overlapping?

Or if this a fool's errand, would it be more efficient to just go for the two Myrrix approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a fine way to approach this. The Collections are 'fake' users. The weight of this type of link might be properly more than 1.

User IDs never appear in the results, so it kind of doesn't matter that they exist. They won't turn up in results.

There is a 'tag' API to accommodate this sort of thing too.